# How to retrieve value of spinner data from MySql database

Tags: android, mysql, android-spinner

I am trying to develop an update form. I have a problem in displaying the value of the spinner for gender. In my MySql database the value of gender is Male. Now i have to display that value in my spinner.

Here's the code for editing patient.

```
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                          this, R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                          adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown

    _item);


protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_patient_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Patient Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PATIENT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            inputusername= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
                            inputpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                            inputfname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
                            inputlname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
                            inputcontact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
                            inputaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
                            inputdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datetext);//bday
                            inputgender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gender);
                            inputage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
                            //rdmale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdmale);
                            //rdfemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdfemale);




                            // display product data in EditText
                            inputusername.setText(product.getString(TAG_USERNAME));
                            inputpassword.setText(product.getString(TAG_PASSWORD));
                            inputfname.setText(product.getString(TAG_FNAME));
                            inputlname.setText(product.getString(TAG_LNAME));
                            inputcontact.setText(product.getString(TAG_CONTACT));
                            inputaddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
                            inputgender.setSelectedItem(product.getString(TAG_GENDER));//it's an error here. help me //how to set value for spinner
                            inputage.setText(product.getString(TAG_AGE));
                            inputdate.setText(product.getString(TAG_BIRTHDAY));
                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditPatientActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving patient ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String username = inputusername.getText().toString();
            String password = inputpassword.getText().toString();
            String fname = inputfname.getText().toString();
            String lname = inputlname.getText().toString();
            String contact = inputcontact.getText().toString();
            String age = inputage.getText().toString();
            String address = inputaddress.getText().toString();
            //String birthday = inputbirthday.getText().toString();
            String gender = inputgender.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String bday = inputdate.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_USERNAME, username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PASSWORD, password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_FNAME, fname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LNAME, lname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ADDRESS, address));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_BIRTHDAY, bday));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_AGE, age));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_GENDER, gender));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_CONTACT, contact));



            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_patient,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

              inputgender.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a string-array in your string.xml file

```
<string-array name="gender">
        <item>Male</item>
        <item>Female</item>
</string-array>
```

and after you retrive your data from database

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"){
      youeSpinner.setSelection(0);
}
else if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("female"){
      youeSpinner.setSelection(1);
}
```

Comment: i have that already in my xml. my problem is that i have to retrieve the value of that gender spinner from database and display it in spinner. For example the user registered his name: allan and gender: male. Now i want to retrieve the value of that spinner (which is Male) in my EditPatient. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Allright! I see you have `R.array.gender_array` already defined now all you have to do is get the corresponding **index** of *male/female* **Strings**.  you can do it like this:

```
if(product.getString(TAG_GENDER).equals("male"))    
     inputgender.setSelection(0);//if male is at 0 position
else
     inputgender.setSelection(1);//if female is at 1 position
```

You need to put this code

```
inputaddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
inputgender.setSelectedItem(......);//HERE REPLACE THIS LINE WITH THE ABOVE CODE
inputage.setText(product.getString(TAG_AGE));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited the answer please vote up and accept answer if it works for you. :) cheers

Comment: I hope that will work. I tried your solution but i don't know if it's working because my app is crashing because of another problem. here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642138/android-error-in-passing-id-of-selected-item-in-listview-using-contextmenu?noredirect=1#comment32707307_21642138